# Explanation regarding output of C program

Tags: c, recursion

```
void count(int n) 
{ 
    static int d=1;
    printf("%d", n);
    printf("%d", d);
    d++;
    if(n>1)
        count(n-1);
    printf("%d", d);
}

void main()
{
    count(3);
}
```

Output calculated by me is 3 1 2 2 1 3 4

And Output given by book 3 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 4

I know why my answer different.

In book solution they are executing printf statement in "if" loop always. But as I study in my book scope of if, for and while loop is up to next statement if parentheses are not present.

After if statement true count is called and printf not get executed. But why they are executing it each time.

Comment: You don't have a loop here. Edit your code please.

Comment: Do you see that there is recursion at play here? It's just like calling the `count` function again and again.

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. The apply the knowledge from that so you can debug this program and understand what's really happening.

Comment: You might apply proper indentation to your code. The indentation creates an optical impression of the structure of your code that does not match the instructions.

Comment: Change your 3 `printf()` to `printf(" A%d" n);` `printf(" B%d" d);` and `printf(" C%d" d);` to get a clearer understanding.

Comment: @babon OK, I've missed this. Still no loops hare. I've edited the indentations to make it more clear.

Comment: "But why they are executing it each time." --> because `printf("%d" d);` is not part of the `if(n>1) count(n-1);` block.

Comment: Your program does not compile. Please post real code. Don't retype your code but copy/paste it.

Comment: Use debugger to see actual values of variables :), simply enter breakpoint where you want and usually works mouse over variables for showing values

Comment: Btw literally that is not a loop, but thing called `recursion` (yes, technically it is working as a loops)- basically "you have to understand recursion for understanding recursion" :)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not give parenthesis to your `if`, `for`, `while` statements they will only execute next line. After changing:

```
if(n>1)
    count(n-1);
printf("%d", d);
```

To:

```
if(n>1){
    count(n-1);
    printf("%d", d);
}
```

Your output will become closer to what you expected it to be:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ gcc main.c -o main
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ ./main  31221344
```

Comment: I want to know my answer is correct? If parentheses not present.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: What is the output if parenthesis not present?

Comment: One more `4` is printed out. Why don;t you compile and test it yourself?

Comment: 3 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 4

Answer (score 1):

```
static d:1
count(n:3)
    print(n)         // 3
    print(d)         // 1
    ++d:2
    count(n:2)
        print(n)     // 2
        print(d)     // 2
        ++d:3
        count(n:1)
            print(n) // 1
            print(d) // 3
            ++d:4
            print(d) // 4
        print(d)     // 4
    print(d)         // 4
```

The first `4` is printed because the `if` guard stopped the recursion. The second `4` is printed as the (recursive) function call for `count(n:1)` has returned. The third `4` is printed as the (recursive) function call to `count(n:2)` has returned.

I think your confusion is that you believe that making a recursive call causes the caller to end any further processing of its function body. But this is not the case, unless there is a `return` statement that ends the function early. For example, if the recursive call was guarded like this:

```
if (n>1) {
    count(n-1);
    return;
}
print("%d", d);
```

Then, the output would match your expectations. Only one `4` would be printed, the one that executed because the `if` evaluated false. All the other recursive calls would execute `return` after completing, so no other `4` will appear.

---

Also note:

```
if (n>1)
    count(n-1);
printf("%d", d);
```

and

```
if (n>1) {
    count(n-1);
}
printf("%d", d);
```

are equivalent. And the code means: print `d` after the `if` block completes. There are two ways for it to complete. One way is when the `if` condition is false. The other way is when the `if` condition is true, the recursive call is performed, and then that call returns. When recursive call returns, the `if` block completes, and then `d` is printed.

---

Further note, while very closely related, and computationally equivalent, recursion cannot be considered an ordinary "loop". A recursive call implies multiple active local stacks, while an ordinary "loop" only has the current local stack, and the loop execution block. Thus, a print statement after an ordinary "loop" will only get executed once, which is after the loop completes. However, code that follows a recursive call will get executed after the recursive call returns. So, if the recursive call is performed 2 times, there are three active local stacks that need to complete. In your code, each of those local stacks want to print `d` after the `if` block completes.

Comment: If parenthesis not present still printf execute. Then it means books are wrong about the scope of loop to next line only if parentheses not present.

Answer (score 0):

If the output by the book is '3 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 4'

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count(int n) 
{ 
    static int d=1;
    printf("\nN IS: %d", n);
    printf("\nD IS: %d", d);
    d++;
    if(n>1) count(n-1);

    printf("\nFINAL D IS: %d", d);
}

int main()
{     
    count(3);
    return 0;
}
```

if not change this:

```
    if(n>1)
    {       
        count(n-1); 
        printf("\nFINAL D IS: %d", d);
    }
```

Comment: I want to know my answer is correct? If parentheses not present.

Comment: What is the expected result ?